# Using tc netem for dynamic delay variations causes packet loss

Tags: linux, tc

I'm trying to use tc netem to simulate a short [0.5, 1.5] second increase in delay in the range [0, 1500ms].

This is done with the command:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp37s0 root netem delay 200ms
```

The delay is then reset after the timeout by either deleting the qdisc

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev enp37s0 root
```

or by changing the delay to 0ms.

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp37s0 root netem delay 0ms
```

If the delay is above 200ms the reset step causes packets to be dropped. I'm assuming this is due to some internal buffer or queue overrunning?

If the delay is e.g. 1500ms, then a high percentage of packets are lost continuously at a rate of 1Mbps with packet sizes of 80 bytes.

Is there any way to prevent this?

I'm not even sure if netem is the correct tool to do this and would appreciate any advice.

In case it helps, I am using iperf to measure packet loss:

```
iperf3 -c <host> -t 1200 -u -l 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using UDP to test the speed (-u). UDP is connectionless and has no congestion control, so it doesn't scale down to available bandwidth like TCP does.

So iperf always generate **udp datagrams** at the constant rate from the start (default 1 Mbit/sec).

Than datagrams are queued by traffic control subsystem to apply queue discipline - qdisc.

Obviously, in order to limit the traffic rate, tc controls rate of dequeuing to match desired bandwidth/latency.

In simplest scenario when queuing rate > dequeuing rate excess datagrams droped before queue because queue is full.

```
       1Mb/s    0.1Mb/s
 process -> queue -> interface
```

This behavior is expected and does not mean that something is wrong.

Try TCP.